# How to deploy and serve prediction using TensorFlow from API?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

From google tutorial we know how to train a model in TensorFlow. But what is the best way to save a trained model, then serve the prediction using a basic minimal python api in production server.

My question is basically for TensorFlow best practices to save the model and serve prediction on live server without compromising speed and memory issue. Since the API server will be running on the background for forever.

A small snippet of python code will be appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[TensorFlow Serving](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving) is a high performance, open source serving system for machine learning models, designed for production environments and optimized for TensorFlow. The initial release contains C++ server and Python client examples based on [gRPC](http://www.grpc.io/). The basic architecture is shown in the diagram below.

[image]

To get started quickly, check out the [tutorial](https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/serving_basic).

Comment: Thanks for this, Jarek. Do you know if there are plans for a python implementation of the server-side for TensortFlow Serving?

Comment: Not that I know of since the core library is in C++ and performance-focused. Can you share more information about your use case?

Comment: That makes sense. I'd like to deploy a server that will ingest requests from a large number of users, which take the form of images, and return the results of an inference (the output of a model whose input is the request image). Whats unclear to me is that much of the documentation (i.e., defining "servables" in the architecutre overview) appears to imply that TensorFlow Serving actually returns the models themselves, rather than their output ("Servables are the underlying objects that clients use to perform computation")... I'd like computation to take place server-side, not client-side

Comment: Yes, in our examples TensorFlow Serving runs inside of a gRPC server and the server returns the result of an inference. Btw, sounds like your system may end up looking similar to what is covered in this tutorial: https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/serving_inception :)